# Unable to install and run a package in R (windows)

Tags: r, package

I am working on a 64 bit windows system. And I have a 64 bit, 2.15.1 version of R installed in it. I am trying to install a package called "MethLAB" from the package menu, by selecting its local zip file from the "Packages" menu. However I am running into an error show below.

```
> utils: : :menuInstallLocal ()
package 'MethLAB' successfully unpacked and MDS sums checked

> library(MethLAB)
> MethLAB()
Warning message:
In file (filename, "r", encoding =encoding) :
  unable to resolve 'bioconductor.org'
```

So the above is what i get when i try to run it. Can anyone help me with its proper installation and running ?

Comment: Maybe [these folks](http://www.justice.gov/dea/) have something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is because you are not connected to the internet. Is that so? If it is then you should contact the people that wrote the package; it seems the software is trying to contact BioConductor for some reason, perhaps to download additional packages/functionality etc. To that end, make sure you have installed all the pre-requisite packages needed to run `**MethLAB**.

Do note that this is a warning only, not an error. Whether this stops the package from working or not is a different matter. Again you should take this up with the developers if you have followed all the instructions on how to install and use the package.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was not connected to the internet. I will try working with it with internet. If it still does not work , i will contact the developers. Thank you again..

Comment: @PoojaMandaviya If this Answers your question, please consider accepting it. This helps improve [so] for all sorts of reasons. See the [ask] section of the FAQ for the details and how to accept questions. Essentially just tick the bick check mark next to the Answer you wish to accept.